# Mysql Foreign key which has a reference to two columns which are primary keys in two different table

Tags: mysql, database

Lets say that there are three tables called teachers, students and messages.

teachers:

```
-----------
ID | name |
-----------
t_1| Dani |
-----------
t_2| Billy|
-----------
```

students:

```
-------------
ID | name   |
-------------
s_1| Luckas |
-------------
s_2| Oliver |
-------------
```

messages:

```
--------------------------------
| ID | sender_ID | receiver_ID |
--------------------------------
| 1  | s_1       | s_2         |
--------------------------------
| 2  | s_1       | t_1         |
--------------------------------
| 3  | s_1       | t_2         |
--------------------------------
| 4  | t_1       | s_2         |
--------------------------------
```

sorry about how the tables looks I did not know how to do it better.

I want that only values from teachers or from students will be permitted to be stored in messages.sender_id and in messages.receiver_Id like in cases of FK.

I need to know whether is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: You mean that students or teachers could be both senders or receivers?

Comment: yes, how can I do it?

Comment: You cannot use foreign keys in this case. Foreign key references fields in a single table. You can use triggers to enforce data integrity

Comment: Use one table `users` for students and teachers with an additional column `role` (student or teacher).

Answer (score 1):

You have two different choices.
First is to create a Person table, and another one PersonType. PersonType will contain "Student" and "Teacher" as values. Add a PersonTypeId to Person and create a foreign key to PersonType, this will act as discriminator between studens and teachers. Add the foreign key to Messages table from Person.

The second is to create "database inheritance". Create the Person table with common data between students and teachers. Then, create Students and Teachers table with the specific data for each, and add a foreign key to Person on both. Add your foreign key to Messages from Person table.
First solution is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support declarative foreign key constraint to enforce this integrity rule. With the tables as shown (i.e. with no changes to the tables), we could use triggers to enforce these kinds of referential integrity rules. It would require a combination of BEFORE INSERT, BEFORE UPDATE, BEFORE DELETE triggers on all three tables.

We don't see any rule that will prevent the same value (for example, `k_9`) from appearing the both the `student` and `teacher` table. So a row in messages that has a `sender_ID` is `k_9`, we wouldn't have a way to determine which that refers to, the `student`, the `teacher` or both.

---

If it is possible to change the table definitions, we could implement a `person` table as a superclass of `student` and `teacher`. A couple patterns for implementing that. One possibility is adding a discriminator column.

```
person
ID    type     name
---   -------  ------
s_1   student  Lukas
s_2   student  Oliver
t_1   teacher  Dani
t_2   teacher  Billy
k_9   student  Rover
```

With that table, declaring foreign key constraints from the `messages` would be straightforward.

We can return the equivalent of the `students` table and the `teachers` table  in the original design:

students

```
SELECT ID, name FROM person WHERE type = 'student'
```

teachers

```
SELECT ID, name FROM person WHERE type = 'teacher'
```

---

But given only the three tables shown in the question, it's not possible to declare foreign key constraints to enforce the specified referential integrity rules. The only way to enforce those kind of integrity rules would be through triggers.

```
BEFORE INSERT ON messages
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- if NEW.sender_ID is non-NULL, verify the value appears
   -- as value in `ID` column of either `students` or `teachers`
   -- if not, throw an error 

   -- if NEW.receiver_ID is non-NULL, verify the value appears 
   -- as value in `ID` column of `students` or `teachers`
   -- if not, throw an error 

END
```

We would also need triggers for UPDATE ON messages, as well as UPDATE and DELETE ON students and teachers